# Git + LaTeX + BitBucket: Sharing image files

Tags: image, git, latex, png, bitbucket

If I am version controlling my LaTeX docs and have a repo on bitbucket which I share with other conotributors, how do I share the `png`/`jpg` etc. files without having git tracking them?
Because every contributor should be able to compile it without LaTeX's `draft` check and visualize the complete paper with images, but it makes no sense to track such images with git (my `.gitignore` has a `img/` line in it)

Comment: Why do you think it does not make sense to track the images with git?

Comment: Why would you take snapshots of binary files? That is not what git is supposed to do I guess

Comment: Git is commonly used to store both text and binary files. I would not use git for storing only binary files, but if my project contains some pics I don't keep them outside git

Comment: If the images are part of the document, for me they are part of the 'source' and they should be stored in git too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the "Downloads" section of your Bitbucket repo. It is made for "adding any file that you would like to make available to your users, such as app binaries", which sounds pretty much like what you need. But you collaborators still have to download / unpack them manually.

Also, you can actually store binaries in Git repos. The problem is that they cannot be "delted" effectively due to Git internals and each binary file modification just duplicates all the bytes, even if you changed only one. So, if you don't change them frequently it's pretty ok. Bitbucket has a limitations on max repo size, so you'll get a warning when it is fool.

Another approach is to use [Git Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/) which is especially created to handle binaries in Git repos. Unfortunately, it is not available on Bitbucket yet. If you can move your repo to Github consider this possibility.